# How to deploy AWS loadbalancer listeners via AWS CDK that redirect and forward to ECS container

Tags: python, iaas, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy a listener on a loadbalancer with the following configuration (manually modified and tested, following CDK deploy):

[image: Listner Configuration]

The following code adds the listener, but doesn't update listener to redirect port 80 to 443 (https) and the HTTPs:443 listener ID is trying to connect with ECS over HTTPS rather than HTTP.

```
    loadbalancer = cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(
        self, 'loadbalancer',
        vpc=p_vpc,
        internet_facing=True,
        load_balancer_name='ppal-alb'
    )

    loadbalancer_listener = cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListener(
        self, 'loadbalancer-listener',
        open=True,
        port=443,
        certificates=[p_certificate],
        load_balancer=loadbalancer
    )

    loadbalancer_listener.add_action(
        'redirect-action',
        action=cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ListenerAction
        .redirect(
            port='443',
            protocol='HTTPS',
            permanent=True)
    )

    target_group_config = cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
        self, 'target-group',
        port=443,
        protocol=cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
        target_type=cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.TargetType.IP,
        vpc=p_vpc
    )

    loadbalancer_listener.add_target_groups(
        'loadbalancer_listener_target_group',
        target_groups=[target_group_config]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` which I hadn't realized automatically added the http listener, so the above action that I had was having no effect.

Turns out this pattern is useful for getting up and running, but removes the fine grained control. The desired behavior is still possible with `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` you just need to add the following options:

```
redirect_http=True,          
protocol=cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
certificate=req_certificate,
domain_name="my_domain_name.com",
domain_zone=cdk.aws_route53.HostedZone.from_lookup(self, f"{id}-hosted-zone", domain_name="my_domain_name.com")
```

This will:

- redirect http to https on the ALB
- forward traffic from https on the ALB to port 80 on the fargate service
- add the A name alias in route53 for the domain

Answer (score -1):

You miss the definition of the HTTP listener in your code. The load balancer should have two listeners - HTTP and HTTPS. In addition, the HTTP listener should have a redirect action.

There are two listeners on your screenshot. The screenshot shows the listeners but not the actions. Each listener should have a default rule and optionally might have other rules. A rule might be a redirect, a fixed response or a forward request to the target group. The `addTargetGroups()` and `addAction()` methods create both a rule and a target group for the listener.

Please check [the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) for more details.

[image]

Adding a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is a prevalent task, and CDK provides a simple solution. The `ApplicationLoadBalancer` class has a method to register a redirect listener. I would recommend using it.

```js
loadbalancer.addRedirect();
```

> If you do not provide any options for this method, it redirects HTTP
> port 80 to HTTPS port 443.